# Страница долго грузится wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, pagespeed

Делаю сайт на вордпрессе, верстаю пишу все сам. Скорость загрузки на мобайле была 70+, на декстопе 90+. Потом по надобности поменял домен, все нормально, работает как надо, картинки и прочее загружаются, но скорость страницы сильно упала аж до 25 и на мобайле и на декстопе.
Я уже отключал все свои скрипты и даже сss стили, но там все еще производительность очень низкая и грузит долго, то есть ошибка не в моих файлах, а в каких-то внутри проекта или внутри вордпресса
Pagespeed показывает следующее:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В консоли такой вот ужас:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И я вообще в душе не знаю, что это за js код, где он и что означают ошибки, так как я ничего не менял и раньше ничего не было подобного. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста

Comment: Ещё б ему быстро грузится.. Одних скриптов и картинок на 10 мб. https://tools.pingdom.com/#6118aba37a000000

Comment: Ну тут проблема для меня именно в скриптах, так как я до этого без того был в процессе исправления медиа, они не суть вопроса, а вот какие-то скрипты, которых раньше не было, а сейчас, как видите, они грузятся очень долго и даже не понятно какие, так как до этого это не было проблемой, пока я домен не сменил

Comment: AdBlock блочит ссылки рекламы, о чем и пишет в консоль) 6+мб только JS.. минифицируйте мб, оптимизируйте картинки) + проверьте ваше интернет соединение с сервером.. у меня быстро загрузилось

Comment: + вы можете в панели разработчика смотреть не только консоль) на вкладке "производительность" вы можете увидеть больше информации

Comment: Картинки я оптимизирую, но js не смогу, так как он ругается на файлы, которые не мои, то есть не я их писал, потому не знаю, откуда это взялось. У меня js на этой странице мало, поэтому для меня вообще загадка откуда наплыло 6мб..

Comment: "не знаю, откуда это взялось" --  там же написано www.youtube.com, у Вас же куча ютуб видосов на странице.

Comment: Имею в виду, что на прошлом домене у меня все еще было куча ютуб видео, но проблем не было. Плюс все эти видео при прогрузки страницы не появляется, так как они все изначально имеют display none, пока не нажмут посмотреть. То, что там отображает, это картинка с кнопкой просто, обложка

Comment: Ну это Вы так думаете. Зайдите во вкладку "Network" в инспекторе, нажмите на "All" а по окончанию прогрузки страницы отсортируйте результат по домену и увидите там кучу www.youtube.com, play.google.com и всякое прочее. Были бы это просто картинки, тот же doubleclick который блочится адблоком не отрабатывал бы.

Comment: Вы же там айфреймы встраиваете. Есть такой плагин Lite YouTube Embed, именно с этим пунктом должен помочь, можете [статью](https://www.kobzarev.com/projects/lite-youtube-embed/) почитать там есть сравнение.

Comment: Спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли